# how to store last character of the world from the string into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string like -

```
$str = "Hello how are you";
```

and i want to store last character in an array then the result look like below-

```
array(0=>o,1=>w,2=>e,3=>u)
```

how It can be achieve without the using of php `explode()`, `substr()` and `array_split()` methods.

Comment: *"without the using of php redefine function"* WHY? That is like asking: "How can I code in PHP without PHP code".

Comment: you can write it by yourself. :/

Comment: Actually this question was putting on me in the interview

Comment: predefined means php inbuilt function like explode(), array_split() etc.

Comment: So what is allowed? Is using loops and accessing array elements allowed? Also what defines as a word separator here?

Comment: In other words, you want to code it in C? All PHP functions are kind of predefined, aren't they

Comment: use anything instead php array functions

Comment: @AmanAttari I think you need to [edit] your question and specific a bit more: What exactly is / isn't allowed? Is for(){} allowed, ...? What counts as a word? Is D.C. a word? Does 2016 count as word?

Comment: substr and strlen is allowed? for is allowed?

Comment: @ Rizier123 I edited my question.

Comment: @AmanAttari So you can use everything except those 3 functions? If yes just use a simple regex to do it: https://3v4l.org/J728B

Comment: So now what? You take this back to the interview and get the job based on somebody else figuring out your problem? Shouldn't the answer get a cut?

Comment: First, the question "What is the last character of the world" needs to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

i dunno why am i doing this but get it

```
$str = "Hello how are you";
$last='';
$i=0;
$result=array();

while ($i<strlen($str)){
if ($str[$i]==' '){
$result[]=$last;    
}
$last= $str[$i];
if ($i==(strlen($str)-1)){
$result[]=$last;        
}
$i++;
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you don't want to use `explode`, `substr` and `split`, so for now you need to use `strlen` for getting the string length.

After getting the array length you need to loop through the length and check if the character is a `blank space` or `last character`. If then add the previous character to the array of output.

```
$str = "Hello how are you";

$length = strlen($str);
$out = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    if($str[$i] == " " || ($i == $length - 1)){
        $out[] = $str[$i-1];
    }
}

print_r($out);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => o
    [1] => w
    [2] => e
    [3] => u
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Also you edited the question yourself so you probably have read: ***without** the using of php explode(), substr()*

Comment: @Rizier123, now i did it using some other functions.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution using `str_word_count` function:

```
$str = "Hello how are you";
$last_chars = [];
foreach (str_word_count($str, 1) as $word) {
    $last_chars[] = $word[strlen($word) - 1];
}

print_r($last_chars);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => o
    [1] => w
    [2] => e
    [3] => u
)
```